# Requesting Full Remote Work as a Reasonable Accommodation for a Drug Side Effect

Tags: remote-work, accommodation

I am currently working in a hybrid model where I go to the office 2 days per week and work from home for the remaining days. I have recently been diagnosed as pre-diabetic and started taking semiglutide medication to manage my A1C levels and assist with weight loss. The medication has been effective in managing my condition.

However, I am experiencing some side effects, including frequent bathroom trips, excessive gas, and an increased need to drink water. These side effects are quite uncomfortable and can be disruptive in an office setting, but manageable from home.

I am considering requesting to work fully remote as a reasonable accommodation for the drug's side effect. I would like to ask the community for advice on the following questions--please feel free to answer any:

1. Do I have grounds to request full remote work as a reasonable accommodation based on the side effects of the medication?
2. How can I improve my odds of getting this request accommodated by my employer?
3. What documentation or medical proof should I provide to support my request?
4. How should I approach discussing this with my manager and HR department?
5. Are there any additional considerations or potential challenges I should be aware of when making this request?

Comment: What country are you in, and how long have you been at the job? Also, is being in the office reasonably required for the job?

Comment: Is your office a normal office with a bathroom, and a kitchen from which you can get drinks? Or are you out in the field, traveling a lot, or otherwise less able to drink and pee than you would be at home?

Comment: You could get a note from the doctor, and present it to your manager or HR. If the doctor's note clearly explains everything, then you have a good chance of success with your request when talking to your manager and HR.

Comment: Do you anticipate resistance to the request?

Comment: From what you've described: Needing to drink often isnot disruptive. Needing to go to the bathroom often is not disruptive except in the middle of a meeting, and even then can be managed. Excessive gas may or may not be a problem that can be solved by putting you downwind from others. I think you may get some pushback on this one unless your doctor is willing to write that it is medically necessary for you to work from home.

Comment: Are you likely to be on this medication long-term or is it a temporary measure? You may be able to arrange something informal with your manager if it's only going to be for a few months, especially if you're unlikely to get official approval of WFH as a reasonable accommodation.

Comment: I like remote work, but this may be a red flag.  While discrimination is wrong, they may be unwilling to accommodate a side-effect.  In the use, this could be under the rubric of the ADA and/or FMLA laws.  I wish you well, but tread carefully, especially if retaining the particular job is important to you, as it normally is for most people.

Answer (score 3):

Most countries/states have well defined set of rules & process that governs accommodations for medical issues and disabilities. I strongly suggest that you read up on those and/or add a location tag to your questions.

In many cases, accommodations are not subject to negotiation or depend on what your and employer think, but they are determined by a medical professional.

If your doctor writes you a note that states you need to work from home, than the company often will have to accommodate, at least to the extent that it renders the job still viable

> Do I have grounds to request full remote work as a reasonable accommodation based on the side effects of the medication?

That's up to your doctor to decide and depends on your local laws,

> How can I improve my odds of getting this request accommodated by my employer?

Ask your doctor first. Read up on local laws and understand your rights and your responsibilities. Understand the process and what the company is legally required to do. Find a solution that's "mutually beneficial", i.e. works for you but isn't the worst case for your employer either.

> What documentation or medical proof should I provide to support my request?

Ask your doctor and a local labor lawyer.

> How should I approach discussing this with my manager and HR department?

I would always start with my manager. Chances are they will pull in HR immediately anyway, since this type of thing is typically out of their jurisdiction anyway.

> Are there any additional considerations or potential challenges I should be aware of when making this request?

It's not going to help you career. I know, it's frustrating and it's unfair but that's the way it is. If you play it right, you can minimize any damage. Be reasonable and make sure you understand what really matters to your employer.

Comment: did you really recommend to go talk to a lawyer?

Comment: If you think you will need to provide proof, and think your employer might quibble about what constitutes proof, then you might want to talk to a lawyer.

Comment: @TigerGuy: of course. A local lawyer can explain your rights, responsibilities and options to you. Doing legal research yourself would definitely be cheaper but that's not everyone's cup of tea.

Comment: I think talking to HR and your manager first might be a good idea before going to a lawyer. Chances are high they are  just going to grant your request.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to figure out whether your medical condition is serious enough that a doctor would write you some recommendation for working from home or not.

If you think that is the case you should get something in writing from your doctor and in most jurisdictions your employer will have to accomodate you. Take the letter from your doctor to HR and they will help.

If you think this is not medical advise but would merely be nice and convenient for you you can still ask your employer. But then you are asking your employer a favor which they may or may not grant depending on a whole range of considerations only some of which are under your control. In this situation you should talk to your direct supervisor. They may not be able to grant it to you but only after you convinced them you can go one level higher.